# Pandas Data Frame filtering based off a column condition

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to remove all the rows from a data frame where a certain condition is met in one column.

Lets say my data frame is this:

```
index  'Value 1'   'Grade'
1         10         2170A
2         15         2170B
3         10         NCR2170B
4         20         NCR2170A
5         30         NCR2170B
```

I want the output after filtering to be this

```
    index  'Value 1'   'Grade'
2         15         2170B
3         10         NCR2170B
5         30         NCR2170B
```

I have tried many different variations of using list comprehension, looping through each row and evaluating.  I can make it work when I use something along the lines of:

```
data_filtered = data[data['Grade'] == '2170B']
```

But this obviously misses entries like NCR2170B.

Whenever I try something like:

```
data_filtered = data['2170B' in data['Grade']]
```

I get Key Error: 'True'.

I feel like I am missing something very obvious here.

I have also tried using np.where but it just outputs an empty array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) to check if a string column contains a sub string:

```
df[df.Grade.str.contains('2170B')]

#index  Value 1    Grade
#1  2        15    2170B
#2  3        10 NCR2170B
#4  5        30 NCR2170B
```

Comment: Thank you so much I knew it was something simple that I wasn't aware of.  Sorry I am new to python.